# Why won't my inline JavaScript function work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What seems to be the problem?
The code doesn't work, the text does not change.

```js
function translate() {
    document.getElementById("tex").innerHTML = "BLABLA";
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center"><font size="100">What Is BLA: </font></h1>
<p id ="tex"><font size="10">BLA</font></p>
<button onclick="translate()">Translate</button>
```

Comment: move button inside the body

Comment: The button is inside O_o

Comment: if you change the function name it works fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/f0x2eHG3aKfrziLtDHxI?p=preview

Answer (score 13):

The problem is in some browsers, like Chrome, DOM elements have a [`translate` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/translate) (MDN does not list Chrome as supporting this feature, but it does have the property). In the context of JavaScript event attributes, those properties [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) any globals of the same name.

If you check your developer console, you should see a message saying that `translate` is not a function because of this.

> Uncaught TypeError: translate is not a function

If you change the name of the function, you will avoid this issue:

```js
function myTranslate() {
    document.getElementById("tex").innerHTML = "BLABLA";
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center"><font size="100">What Is BLA: </font></h1>
<p id ="tex"><font size="10">BLA</font></p>
<button onclick="myTranslate()">Translate</button>
```

Comment: This is the problem at hand, yes! I was trying to dig up some documentation to verify it so I didn't write up an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also to note is that you are trying to set the `innerHTML` of the `p` element with the id `tex`. But the element has a child element in it. You can set the `innerHTML` property of that item.

```
document.getElementById("tex").childNodes[0].innerHTML = "BLABLA";
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't use the `<font>` tag and use CSS instead!

Comment: Agreed, don't use the font tag